# Find the percentile of random variable X with a normal distribution using standard normal distribution

Tags: probability, statistics, normal-distribution

Need help finding the 80th percentile of random variable  X  with a normal distribution with  $μ_X = 80, σ_X = 10,$ using standard normal distribution
 and also the 90th percentile when $μ_X = 12, σ_X = 1.$

I get that you start off with $x = μ+zσ,$ but then I have no clue where to go with since I don't know what $X$ and $Z$ are.

Comment: My 2 cents... start with $ P(X \le a ) = .8$ which as you noted is equal to $ P(\mu+Z\sigma \le a ) = .8$ and now get the $Z$ by itself on the LHS and use the Z table to figure out  what the right side should be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can standardize the random variable: $Z=\frac{X-\mu_x}{\sigma_x}$, with $Z\sim \mathcal N(0,1)$

Then the equation is $P(X\leq x)=\Phi\left(\frac{x-\mu_x}{\sigma_x}\right)=\Phi\left(\frac{x-80}{10}\right)=0.8$

Inverse function

$\frac{x-80}{10}=\Phi^{-1}\left(0.8\right)$

Now you take a [table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_normal_table#Cumulative) of a standard normal distribution (cummulative) and look for the value of $z$ where $\Phi(z)\approx 0.8$. This is at $z=0.84$ I have circled the number.

[image]Thus the equation becomes

$\frac{x-80}{10}=0.84$

I think you can proceed. Just solve the equation for $x$.

Comment: Thanks, I think my mistake was trying to find a way to do it without a software or table, lack of research on my side. Thanks

Comment: @DJBay Yes, without a table it is mostly impossible to obtain a sufficient accurate result. One exeption is $P(X>\mu)=P(X<\mu)=0.5$, where $X\sim \mathcal N(\mu,\sigma^2)$

Answer (score 1):

**With technology.** Using software instead of printed tables, you can get exact answers.
In R, the function `qnorm` is the inverse CDF (also called the quantile
function) of a specified normal distribution. So answer (a) is about 88.416 and (b) is about 13.282.

```
qnorm(.8, 80, 10);  qnorm(.90, 12, 1)
[1] 88.41621
[1] 13.28155
```

Some statistical calculators and many kinds of statistical software will do such computations.

**With printed standard normal CDF tables.** Some precision is lost using printed tables because you will usually not
be able to find *exactly* the desired value in the body of a normal table.

For (b), if $X \sim \mathsf{Norm}(\mu = 12,\, \sigma=1),$ then
$$P(X \le c) = P\left(\frac{X-\mu}{\sigma} \le \frac{c - 12}{1}\right) = P(Z < c - 12) = 0.9,$$

where $Z$ is standard normal.

Find the (four-place) value in the *body* of the table
that cuts (as nearly as possible to) 10% of the area from the upper tail of $\mathsf{Norm}(0,1).$

That will be the value in the table corresponding to 
$z = 1.28$ in the *margins* of the table. Then $1.28 = c - 12,$ so  $c = 13.28,$ to two places. (By interpolation, you might be able to get an accurate
digit in the third decimal place.)